Saving the value of a function that adds values to the counter every second in the clicker game
I have a mini-game clicker on JS that saves the number of coins and upgrades to the number of coins per click via localStorage. But I can't make a save with a coin upgrade per second in any way. I would be very grateful if you could help me with this, thank you in advance!  I'm attaching the code


//                                           ============= GLOBAL VARIABLES =============

var money = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('moneys')),//global player's money
    clickGain = 1,//money gain on clicker clicked =
    autoGain = 1,//parseInt(localStorage.getItem('autoGains')),//auto money gain
    interval;//auto money interval
    
if (clickGain >= 1){
        clickGain = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('clickGains'));
    }




// HTML MAIN ELEMENTS (except  shop buttons)
var element = {
    clicker   : document.getElementById("main-clicker"),//button
    money     : document.getElementById("money"),//txt
}

//                                          ============= GLOBAL FUNCTIONS =============

function addMoney() { // onClicker pressed add ClickGain
  money = money + clickGain;
  
  
  localStorage.setItem('moneys', money);
  localStorage.setItem('clickGains', clickGain);
  localStorage.setItem('autoGains', autoGain);
}

function updateMoney(check=true) {//update html money txt
  text = "JUMPS: " + money;
  element.money.innerHTML = text;
  if(check){checkPrices();}
  
/*if (autoGain >= 1){
        autoGain = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('autoGains'));
    }*/

}
function autoMoney(amount) {//auto add money every interval
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = setInterval(function(){ money = money + autoGain; updateMoney(); }, 200 / amount);
}

//called when a shop Element was bought
function checkPrices() {
    //Check price for each shop element
    //unlock purchase button if enough money
    for(let i=0;i<shop.length;i++){
        if(money >= shop[i].price){
            shop[i].element.disabled = false;
        }
    }
}
//called when a shop Element was bought
function onBuy(obj) {
    //update money
    money -= obj.price;
    updateMoney(check=false);
    //localStorage.setItem('moneys', money);
    //localStorage.setItem('clickGain', clickGain);
    //localStorage.setItem('autoGain', autoGain);
    //lock every purchase buttons in shop
    for(let i=0;i<shop.length;i++){
        shop[i].element.disabled = true;
    }
}

//                                       ============= SHOP BUTTON CLASS =============

class ShopElement{
    // Object for elements in the shop.
    // New Instance Token:
    //   id -> html main element id (in Html)
    //   newprice_func -> the new price formula function
    //   onclick_func  -> the onClick function
    
    constructor (id,newprice_func,onclick_func) 
    { //constructor: called on "new ShopElement()"
        this.id = id;
        this.element = document.getElementById(id);
        this.element.onclick = this.purchase.bind(this);
        this.text_element = this.element.getElementsByTagName("b")[0];
        
        this._updatePrice = newprice_func;
        this._onClick = onclick_func;
        
        this.price = 0;
        this.purchaseLvl = 1;
        this.updatePrice();
    }
    
    //Call default functions with this as argument
    onClick(){this._onClick(this);}
    updatePrice(){this._updatePrice(this);}
    
    //Update Button's txt price
    updateText(){
        this.text_element.innerHTML = "<b>" +'$'+this.price+': ' + "</b>";}
    
    // Update Every new purchase
    update(){
        this.updatePrice(); //calculate new price
        this.updateText();  //update displayed txt
    }
    // called on Element clicked
    purchase(){
        this.purchaseLvl += 1;
        this.onClick();
        onBuy(this);
        this.update()
        checkPrices();
    }
    
}

//                                   =============== SHOP BUTTONS & FUNCTIONS ===============

//alls buttons functions ( newPriceFormula , onClick )
function newPrice1(obj){obj.price = clickGain * 25 * obj.purchaseLvl;}
function newPrice2(obj){obj.price = 250 * obj.purchaseLvl;}
function newPrice3(obj){obj.price = autoGain * 30 * obj.purchaseLvl + 900;}
function newPrice4(obj){obj.price = clickGain * 25 * obj.purchaseLvl;}
function newPrice5(obj){obj.price = clickGain * 550 * obj.purchaseLvl;}
function onClick1(obj){clickGain*=2;}
function onClick2(obj){autoMoney(this.purchaseLvl);}
function onClick3(obj){autoGain*=2;}
function onClick4(obj){clickGain*=2;}
function onClick5(obj){clickGain*=5;}



//all shop's buttons
shop = [
    //new ShopElement("b1",newPrice1,onClick1),
    new ShopElement("b2",newPrice2,onClick2),
    new ShopElement("b3",newPrice3,onClick3),
    new ShopElement("b4",newPrice4,onClick4),
    new ShopElement("b5",newPrice5,onClick5),
    
    //new ShopElement("b4",newPrice4,onClick3),
];

//                                           ================= START =================

// FIRST UPDATE (on page loaded)
updateMoney(); //money txt
for (let i=0;i<shop.length;i++){
    shop[i].update() //buttons txt & price
}

//set main clicker function onClick
element.clicker.onclick = function() { 
    element.clicker.disabled = true;
    addMoney(); updateMoney(); 
    element.clicker.disabled = false;
};




I tried to use localStorage with both the money and clickGain variables, but without success

The code does not run without the html part. Add html part.
Can you also specify which variable you want to save to local storage?

I managed to understand that my code with localstorage does not work on the server and I do not know why. At startup index.html everything works, and after uploading to the server everything stops working, it gives the value NaN
